# How to unmarshal JSON into interface{} in Go?

Tags: json, go

I'm a newbie in Go and now I have a problem. I have a type called Message, it is a struct like this:

```
type Message struct {
    Cmd string `json:"cmd"`
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

I also have a type called CreateMessage like this:

```
type CreateMessage struct {
    Conf map[string]int `json:"conf"`
    Info map[string]int `json:"info"`
}
```

And I have a JSON string like `{"cmd":"create","data":{"conf":{"a":1},"info":{"b":2}}}`.

When I use `json.Unmarshal` to decode that into a Message variable, the answer is `{Cmd:create Data:map[conf:map[a:1] info:map[b:2]]}`.

So could I decode the JSON into a Message struct and change its Data's interface{} to type CreateMessage according to the Cmd?

I tried to convert Data directly into type CreateMessage but the complier told me that Data is a map[sting]interface{} type.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Define a struct type for the fixed part of the message with a [json.RawMessage](http://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) field to capture the variant part of the message. Define struct types for each of the variant types and decode to them based on the the command.

```
type Message struct {
  Cmd string `json:"cmd"`
  Data      json.RawMessage
}  

type CreateMessage struct {
    Conf map[string]int `json:"conf"`
    Info map[string]int `json:"info"`
}  

func main() {
    var m Message
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    switch m.Cmd {
    case "create":
        var cm CreateMessage
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(m.Data), &cm); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(m.Cmd, cm.Conf, cm.Info)
    default:
        log.Fatal("bad command")
    }
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/aAFa3yxYP4)