# How to unmarshal from interface{} to interface{} in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

There are multiple nodes in my system which communicate through RPC. I am trying to send a map[string] interface{} to another node through RPC. Sender uses json.Marshal and receiver uses json.Unmarshal to get the map. 
Let us say at the sender side, map contains [1] => 2 where 2 is of type uint32.
The problem is Unmarshal tries to find the type of underlying data and converts 2 to float64 type according to its default behavior as specified here https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go. Later, casting float64 to uint32 causes panic.

I refered to [How to unmarshal json into interface{} in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254102/how-to-unmarshal-json-into-interface-in-golang) . But for this, we need to know the type of data. In my case data can be of any type so I want to keep it as interface{}. How do I unmarshal from interface{} to interface{}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately using the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package you can't, because type information is not transmitted, and JSON numbers by default are unmarshaled into values of `float64` type if type information is not present. You would need to define `struct` types where you explicitly state the field is of type `uint32`.

Alternatively you may opt to use [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) which does transmit and preserve type information. See this example:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{"1": uint32(1)}

b := &bytes.Buffer{}
gob.NewEncoder(b).Encode(m)

var m2 map[string]interface{}
gob.NewDecoder(b).Decode(&m2)
fmt.Printf("%T\n%#v\n", m2["1"], m2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lMSh_vLUQR)):

```
uint32
map[string]interface {}{"1":0x1}
```

The downside of `gob` is that it's Go-specific unlike the language and platform independent JSON.